# Android Webview text selection handles

Tags: android, webview

I've overridden the default blue text selection handles in most of my app by adding these items to the app theme and adding the appropriate 9 patch drawables:

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
```

However, this doesn't apply to text selection in a WebView (the blue handles are still there). How can I override the corresponding items in the WebView style?

Comment: May be you can have a look at this [crbug: Overriding Selection Controls in Web-view](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476536). May be helpful to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

WebView seems to be referencing the system resources (e.g. `android.R.attr.textSelectHandleLeft` etc) directly for drawing the handles on its own:
http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/input/HandleView.java

So, I'd say there's no way to re-style them.

Comment: Link is broken. May be you can update it [chromium/HandleViewResources.java](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/input/HandleViewResources.java)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own theme resources and reference them in your Android Manifest.

create your own theme and put it inside `res/values`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft"> 
            @drawable/my_own_handle
        </item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">
            @drawable/my_own_handle
        </item>
     </style>
 </resources>
```

refer your own in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

PS: Referred from [crbug: Overriding Selection Controls in Web view](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476536#c27)